# Keychain issue when trying to set up Enthought enpkg on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, ssh, terminal, enthought

In the past, I was able to successfully set up `enpkg` on my laptop via

```
$ enpkg --userpass
```

I'm pretty sure I initially set it up under 10.8. or earlier. I'm trying to do the same on a machine in my lab, runnning 10.8.2. When I run the aforementioned `$ enpkg --userpass` I'm presented with a stack dump ending with:

> keyring.backend.PasswordSetError: Can't store password in keychain

after entering the username and password. I've noticed a small version difference; my lab machine (the offender) is:

```
haptic:~ flip$ enpkg --version
enstaller version: 4.5.0
```

whereas my laptop is running 4.5.6. I'm at a sort of double-edged problem here, because I can't update enpkg until I can set it up, perhaps other than a full reinstall.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured the problem out.

In the question, I was `ssh`d in to the lab machine when running the `enpkg` command.

I went to the machine proper, logged in, ran `Terminal`.

It appears that it carefully unlocks the keychain when logged in via the Mac OS GUI but not when you `ssh` in. Thus, I was able to properly configure it.

So, this might be a problem if Enthought is to be deployed on, say, a rack of headless Macs.

Comment: It is possible to use enpkg in a rack of headless macs, you just need to unlock your keychain first with 'security unlock-keychain'. This is a bug in keyring (the underlying lib we're using in enstaller: https://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib/issue/54/os-x-get-set_password-fail-when-the)

Answer (score 4):

I've just had this issue as well -- it prevents package updates when running over SSH which is problematic.  I'm running enstaller 4.6.2 on OS X 10.6.8.

The solution is to **unlock** the OS X user login keychain from the SSH session before running `enpkg --userpass`:

```
security unlock-keychain
enpkg --userpass                            # now password can be stored in keychain
```

Comment: The `login-keychain` command is optional.  `unlock-keychain` unlocks the default keychain which enpkg uses. `security unlock-keychain` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as updating enpkg (enstaller) goes, you shouldn't need any credentials to do so.  That is, you should be able to update enpkg without being able to successfully run `enpkg --userpass`.

Comment: Indeed I was- good point. The keychain stuff I've not been able to handle. (I just updated it on the machine proper rather than via `ssh`) I've also noticed that there are command-line tools for dealing with the keychain (see `security` command) but they don't seem to have what one needs in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Manually disabling `keyring.backend.OSXKeychain()` in
`Library/EPD/2.7-64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/config.py` seems to work.

Comment: this is a poor workaround, the correct solution is the one from spinup